# How to reference vertical cells on a separate sheet horizontally (but every nth cell horizontally)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Just to preface this is quite a unique ask and I've googled a bunch of times and never seen the combination of these factors being asked before.

Essentially I have 2 sheets. `'Sheet'` & `'Sheet2'`

'Sheet' has

```
A1:3

A2:4

A3:8

A4:4
```

And So on with random amounts for a few hundred cells. I want `'Sheet2'` to display the following and allow me to drag it to extrapolate it. The reason it is every nth cell is because those cells are merged (i.e `A1-D1` is merged).

```
A1:('Sheet1'A1)    E1:('Sheet1'A2)     I1:(Sheet1'A3)   M1:('Sheet1'A4)
```

and so on

I can extrapolate the data with `=OFFSET(Sheet!$A1,COLUMN()-1,0)` but it skips the missing data on cells `A2` & `A3` and creates `A1:('Sheet1'A1)` `E1:('Sheet1'A4)` instead.

Comment: Did you know that `A1:3` is a valid range reference? Anyway, by `A1:3` you mean that the value of A1 is 3, right?

Comment: `A1-D1` in A1 notation should be referred as `A1:D1`, `('Sheet1'A1')` as `Sheet1!A1`, etc.

Comment: Sorry ya I'm probably referencing things wrong. I don't post a lot about Excel so I don't know the proper etiquette. I was trying to say the value of A1 is 3, A2 is 4 etc. Ya referencing sheets properly I'm also bad at describing.

Answer (score 2):

A simple pull-across formula would be

```
=index(Sheet1!$A:$A,(column()+3)/4)
```

Or an array formula

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup((column(2:2)+3)/4,{row(Sheet1!A:A),Sheet1!A:A},2))
```

Assuming there are enough merged cells available to hold all the data in sheet 1.

Sheet 1

[image]

Sheet 2

[image]